# How to Set Top Alignment in Multirow Table

Tags: spacing, longtable, multirow

So, I have `longtable` with `multirow` which splits to the next page.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-1.2cm}{0.7cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\section}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Random Text}
    \section{Section Name}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \vspace*{-5mm}
    \begingroup
    \setlength\extrarowheight{11pt}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{9cm}|}
            \caption{Insert caption here.}
            \label{tabel1}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{No.}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Text}}\\
            \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{1}&Row One&Row One One\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row 2&Row Two Two\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Three&Row Three Three\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Four&Row Four Four\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Five&Row Five Five\\
            \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{2}&Row One Again&Row One One Again\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row 2&\lipsum[3]\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Three&Row Three Three\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Four&Row Four Four\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Row Five&Row Five Five\\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \endgroup
    \vspace*{-12mm}
    \section{Section Name 2}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The problem is:

[image]

How to reduce the spaces (red lines) so the table can be tidier?

Comment: you can change the code of your `multirow` to `\multirow{1}{*}{1}` or even a decimal number or even a negative number in the first bracket option to do fine tuning for the location of your content

Comment: Aside: Never, ever encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment. No exceptions. None. Why? Because `longtable` environments are already centered horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\multirow{1}{*}{1}
    &Row One
        &Row One One\\ \cline{2-3}
```

Comment: You could go even farther: Replace `\multirow{1}{*}{1}` with `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much